# How much do winter wolves go for?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

In the campaign I'm running one of my players recently acquired 3 winter wolf pups that they're looking to sell. I looked in the books for any idea on how much gold I should give them for each but I couldn't find anything. I want to make sure I don't give them too much/too little

Comment: What level are the PCs? Were the pups given to them or were they taken from, like, a dungeon?

Comment: @daze413 they're all level 3 and they were taken from a small cave they were sent to clear out

Comment: How can you sell this cute puppies, you monster! ;) Train them to be your Wolf Cavalry!

Comment: @DennisChristian if only I could make them keep them hahaha

Answer (score 6):

You're right, it's not in the books. However, you can use the Treasure Horde table in DMG page 133 for guidance.

Make the gold gained from selling the pups part of the treasure horde. With a CR5 Winter Wolf, that would bring us to the Treasure Horde 5-10 table, at an average 3,857 gold for the whole litter, roughly 1280~ gp per cute puppy.

Comment: Although I can't imagine who would buy them at that price...

Comment: I feel like it's also worth noting that Winter Wolves are inherently evil and intelligent enough to speak and hold simple conversations (per the MM). You're essentially selling a sentient creature into slavery, and any buyer willing to part with thousands of gold will probably know these things are going to grow up into monsters. I'm not saying you can't sell them or the price is wrong, but thought I'd mention it as things to keep in mind while playing it all out.

Comment: @Euch Nonplanar creatures with intelligence are not "inherently" evil, the alignment listed on their entry are the majority, it is entirely up to the DM whether they are born that way or learn it from their parents/"village". Any prime material denizen with intelligence is capable of learning and making choices, including alignment slant.

Comment: @Ladifas I can imagine people buying them. Consider similarly powerful creatures can be bought as well, a Shield Guardian costs 1,500 gp; even flesh golems cost 50,000gp. The amount of eccentric rich people in DnD _is_ pretty high.

Comment: @euch creatures dont have inherent alignment in this. if raised by someone nice, they wont be evil at all

Comment: Could be interesting if buyer became a villain? Party would have to potentially fight the grown pups.